# Linux slow outgoing connection

Tags: linux, tcp

I have Debian 8.5 installed and I am facing really strange issue:

Establishing new connection from my linux server to any other server is taking up to 40 seconds. Incoming connections are fine. For example "ping google.com":

```
root@server:~# ping google.com
PING google.com (172.217.18.238) 56(84) bytes of data.
even after 10 minutes nothing more happens
```

Connection from this server to remote MySQL server takes about 6 minutes...

The server is hosted at OVH and the Debian 8.5 is in default minimal configuration there are no any firewalls or any other software installed, the only soft installed is Java 8, screen and Midnight Commander.